# How to update and subtract columns from two tables in a single query with where clause in php.?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to subtract two columns (qty) in a single query and get it updated.With where clause of 2 identities.
Here is what i am trying.

```
 $query="
UPDATE all_stores 
  LEFT JOIN i_v
   ON  all_stores.name = i_v.name 
       SET all_stores.qty = (all_stores.qty - i_v.qty )
";
 
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute($data);
```

here 'all_stores' and 'i_v' are the tables
and i want 'data' to be updated in all_stores table in column 'qty'.

Comment: (1) What is the issue with your query?  (2) Sample data and desired results might clarify what you want to do.

Comment: You are using left join for table 'i_v' which means not all columns in 'all_stores' will get updated...only those returned by the left join will get updated.

Comment: I would use a FULL join as @Nikster2014 says not much point in the left join ````UPDATE table_a JOIN table_b ON table_a.name = table_b.name SET table_a.qty = (table_a.qty - table_b.qty) WHERE table_a.name = table_b.name;````

Comment: @futureweb this is able to reduce the qty from a field but when i do multiple entries, 'table_b.qty' is taking the first value only.